# Silverstripe userform module, adding custom fields

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm adding a custom drop down to the userform module and everything seemed to work, however:

If I set the following: 
[Textfield One] - Dropdown option one
[Textfield Two] - Dropdown option two

It seems to only save the the setting under Textfield One, and ignores Textfield Two. If I then go back and set Textfield Two again, it wipes out Textfield One.

Am I supposed to iterate over something save each value independently or ...?

The class;

```
class CustomEditableFormField extends DataExtension
{
   public function updateFieldConfiguration(FieldList $fields)
   {
    $fields->push(DropdownField::create($this->owner->getSettingName('CustomTextId'), 'Custom field')
        ->setSource(array("1" => "One", "2" => "Two"))
        ->setEmptyString($this->owner->getSetting('CustomTextId')));
   }
 }
```

and my config.yml

```
EditableFormField:
  extensions:
   - CustomEditableFormField
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to add a custom extension is:

```
public function updateFieldConfiguration(FieldList $fields)
{
    $fields->push(DropdownField::create(
        $this->owner->getSettingName('CustomTextId'),
        'Custom  field',
        $this->getData(),
        $this->owner->getSetting('CustomTextId'))
    );
}
```

The main issue being in where the getSetting function is called.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to subclass EditableFormField, not decorate it.

The general rule of thumb is one field to one piece of data too (but not necessarily).

And that form fields are generic, not specific to a purpose, as that's why they're editable rather than an unending array of use-cases.

So I'm not sure this solution is what you're after.

Especially since EditableFormField::getFieldConfiguration() does not take *any* parameters, let alone an entire FieldList.

It seems like you're trying to just skip the configuration step of adding a form field, in which case a custom *subclass* is surely your answer.